# How to read or modify other traveler's date of birth for United Airlines flights?

Tags: bookings, united-airlines

I've booked an intercontinental United Airline flight to the US for me and some friends of mine. The UA site requires to enter the date of birth and the gender of all the passengers, specifying that due to TSA requirements they should match those reported in the passports.

Now, indeed, I've checked several times the details before booking but, *indeed*, I'd like to recheck them again. However, I can check and modify my date of birth from my account, but there seems to be no way of even reading the other traveller's details to check that everything is correct.

Would it work to tell my friends to create an account on the UA site and then associating the booked flight? Should I wait until check-in? Is there any other way?

Comment: Just as a guess: when you go to My Trips on united.com, you're asked for a confirmation number and last name.  What happens if you enter your friend's last name instead of yours?

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks, I've tried, but it neither allows me to read the personal information nor to change it. I'll wait Monday and call the service desk, as suggested by Hilmar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have added your friends to your own United profile as "saved travelers" you can see and edit them there under "Profile & Preferences"->"Personal Information"->"Saved Travellers". That's good practice anyway, since it can help in cases where they travel and you are not around (for any reason).

If you didn't save them you probably have to call United. I would add them to your profile and then ask the United agent to connect them to the booking.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually in the latter situation. On Monday I'll call the service desk and see what they can do.